# Razor View Page cannot be added as a new Item - Visual Studio 2010 

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

Background:
I used to have VS2010 Professional. Upgraded to VS2010 Ultimate. Installed SP1. Installed MVC3, [MVC3 Tools Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1491)

I'm currently working on some custom Orchard modules, and for some reason, I don't see Razor as an installed template. But if I fire up a new ASP.NET MVC3 app, I see it. Has anyone ran into this issue. I've tried uninstalling MVC3 and Tools Update. No luck. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

MVC3 app - as you can see MVC3 View Page (Razor) is available...
[image]

From an Orchard Module:
[image]

Comment: What is your target framework in your project? I've seen that mess around with me before.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried to install the Razor engine as a NuGet Package for this solution? Open Package Manager Console (View - Other windows) and enter

```
  Install-Package RazorEngine
```

Is the System.Web.Mvc.dll included in the references?

Answer (score 5):

For me editing the project file and adding the value `{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}` in front of the others guid's for `<projecttypeguids>` solved the problem.